# How to get the mapping entity in PrePersist LifecycleEvent within a form in Symfony2 for a OneToOne relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities in my code: Session and SessionPicture.

There is a OneToOne relationship between Session and SessionPicture. Session is the mapping entity and SessionPicture the inverse one.

I have a SessionType form, which embeds a SessionPictureType form. I would like the user to be able to upload an image for each session when he fille the SessionType form.

The SessionPicture class contains a file attribute (UploadedFile class) and I have used LifecycleEvents to upload the image file and save it in the right directory.

This is what my code looks for the session class:

```
/**
 * Session
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Entity\SessionRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Session
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\SessionPicture", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, inversedBy="session")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="session_picture_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
    */
    private $sessionPicture;

    /**


* Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Session
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
        /**
         * Set sessionPicture
         *
         * @param \MyBundle\Entity\SessionPicture $sessionPicture
         *
         * @return Session
         */
        public function setSessionPicture(MyBundle\Entity\SessionPicture $sessionPicture = null)
        {
            $this->sessionPicture = $sessionPicture;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get sessionPicture
         *
         * @return \MyBundle\Session\SessionPicture
         */
        public function getSessionPicture()
        {
            return $this->sessionPicture;
        }
```

And this one for my SessionPicture class:

```
/**
 * SessionPicture
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="at_session_picture")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Entity\SessionPictureRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class SessionPicture
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="extension", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $extension;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $alt;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $path;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Session", mappedBy="sessionPicture")
*/
private $session;

public $file;

private $fileNameForRemove;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set extension
 *
 * @param string $extension
 *
 * @return SessionPicture
 */
public function setExtension($extension)
{
    $this->extension = $extension;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get extension
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getExtension()
{
    return $this->extension;
}

/**
 * Set alt
 *
 * @param string $alt
 *
 * @return SessionPicture
 */
public function setAlt($alt)
{
    $this->alt = $alt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get alt
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAlt()
{
    return $this->alt;
}

/**
 * Set path
 *
 * @param string $path
 *
 * @return SessionPicture
 */
public function setPath($path)
{
    $this->path = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get path
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}

/**
 * Set session
 *
 * @param \MyBundle\Entity\Session $session
 *
 * @return SessionPicture
 */
public function setSession(\NyBundle\Entity\Session $session = null)
{
    $this->session = $session;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get session
 *
 * @return \MyBundle\Entity\Session
 */
public function getSession()
{
    return $this->session;
}


/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
*/
public function preUpload()
{
    if($this->file === null)
        return ;
    $extension = $this->file->guessExtension();
    $name = $this->getSession()->getName();

    $this->extension = (string)$extension;
    $this->alt = (string)strval($name);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
*/
public function upload()
{
    $this->path = $this->alt.'.'.$this->extension;

    if ($this->file === null)
        return ;
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);
    unset($this->file);
}
```

I would like to draw your attention on the preUpload() function in my SessionPicture.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
*/
public function preUpload()
{
    if($this->file === null)
        return ;
    $extension = $this->file->guessExtension();
    $name = $this->getSession()->getName();

    $this->extension = (string)$extension;
    $this->alt = (string)strval($name);
}
```

I use this function to give my SessionPicture the same name as the mapping session name and save it in my server with the same name after form validation. Below is an excerpt of my SessionType.php. As you can notice, I embedded a SessionPictureType inside my SessionType.

```
class SessionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'required' => true
            ))
            ->add('sessionPicture', new SessionPictureType(), array(
                'required' => false
                ))
            ->add('Submit', 'submit');
```

When I validate this form, I get the error

> Error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object

It seems that in my preUpload() function in my SessionPicture.php, trying to call $this->getSession() returns nothing instead of returning the mapping session. The same applies if I use $this->getSession() in the upload function.

Can anyone help with that? How can I get the mapping entity before or during form validation and use it in my inversing entity to update its attributes?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It shouldn't cause you any problems when validating the form, do you have any constraints on the form or the Entities? (it would definitely throw the error when you try to flush the `Entity Manager`)

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply.

I don't have any constraints on the form or the entities on theses properties.

I tried to add an eventListener to my SessionType.php, in order to set the session manually on my sessionPicture but it still throws the same error.

Do you have any idea? I believe it must an order issue, since I call the getName() method on sessionPicture and it has not been persisted, same applies for the mapping Session, so Doctrine cannot get the session entity.
What do you think?